# Vulcanize: inlineCss not working on Polymer 1.0 project

Tags: polymer, gulp, polymer-1.0

I have a Polymer 1.0 project, which I want to Vulcanize for production. I use Gulp with `gulp-vulcanize` in order to do so.

My `gulpfile.js` file:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var Vulcanize = require('gulp-vulcanize');

gulp.task('vulcanize', function () {
    return gulp.src('./src/app.html')
        .pipe(Vulcanize({
            inlineCss: true
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'));
});
```

The content of the `src/app.html` is the following:

```
<!-- Polymer elements -->
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/google-map/google-map.html" />
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-icons/iron-icons.html" />
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-button/paper-button.html" />
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-drawer-panel/paper-drawer-panel.html" />
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-icon-button/paper-icon-button.html" />
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-item/paper-item.html" />
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-material/paper-material.html" />
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-menu/paper-menu.html" />
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-progress/paper-progress.html" />
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-scroll-header-panel/paper-scroll-header-panel.html" />
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-toast/paper-toast.html" />
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-toolbar/paper-toolbar.html" />
```

**The problem**: the process doesn't finish nor produces an error.

The CMD output when running `gulp vulcanize`:

```
C:\Stuff\myApp>gulp vulcanize
[15:45:06] Using gulpfile C:\Stuff\myApp\gulpfile.js
[15:45:06] Starting 'vulcanize'...

C:\Stuff\myApp>
```

**However**, the process *does* run when I set `inlineCss` to `false`. The CMD output in this case is:

```
C:\Stuff\myApp>gulp vulcanize
[15:44:55] Using gulpfile C:\Stuff\myApp\gulpfile.js
[15:44:55] Starting 'vulcanize'...
[15:44:55] Finished 'vulcanize' after 581 ms

C:\Stuff\myApp>
```

But, obviously, the CSS is *not* in-lined.

**EDIT**:

I have now ran vulcanize as a standalone tool and got this error:

```
{ [Error: ENOENT, open 'C:\Stuff\myApp\wer_components\paper-drawer-panel\paper-drawer-panel.css']
    errno: 34,
    code: 'ENOENT',
    path: 'C:\\Stuff\\myApp\\wer_components\\paper-drawer-panel\\paper-drawer-panel.css' }
Error: ENOENT, open 'C:\Stuff\myApp\wer_components\paper-drawer-panel\paper-drawer-panel.css'
```

Notice that it tries to access `C:\Stuff\myApp\wer_components` folder instead of `C:\Stuff\myApp\bower_components`. Somehow it looses `bo` in the folder name, but I can't seem to figure out how.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have solved the issue, but the solution is somewhat unusual. First, I read a lot about problems with absolute paths, so I have changed all the paths from absolute to relative and supplied the `abspath: ''` option.

However, this still didn't solve the problem, as I was getting the `no resolver found` error, which is also related to the absolute path problem.

After a lucky guess, I have found the culprit - `fonts.googleapis.com`.

Why is this a problem? The CSS include for the external and Google hosted fonts is the following:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300,300italic,400italic,500,500italic,700,700italic">
```

They use protocol-less URLs in order to preserve the HTTP(s) state of the current page. But this notation has two slashes (`//`) at the beginning of the path and it somewhat confuses the in-lining process. It probably treats the path as file not as URL.

So, the complete fix for the gulp task is the following:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var Vulcanize = require('gulp-vulcanize');

gulp.task('vulcanize', function () {
    return gulp.src('src/app.html')
        .pipe(Vulcanize({
            abspath: '',
            inlineScripts: true,
            inlineCss: true,
            stripExcludes: false,
            excludes: ['//fonts.googleapis.com/*'],
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

Hope somebody else finds this useful.

Also, if somebody thinks the `//` path problem is a bug, please report it.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. Currently there is a bug with inlineCSS. You can read more at https://github.com/PolymerElements/polymer-starter-kit/issues/62

Comment: Thanks for the find. I was afraid it will be a bug since my example is really simple and taken from the documentation. Any workaround until they fix it?

Comment: I've tried to concat the css files that I need, but that introduce a bugs with the components that have equal css classes. Now I am back to square one

Comment: Although your post didn't solve the problem, I have given you the bounty since it would expire tomorrow (and nobody would get it). If you manage to solve it, I will also give you the "Accepted answer".

Comment: I have solved the issue and posted the answer. Does this also solve your problem?

Comment: Later today I will check if this will fix my problem, too.

Answer (score 1):

Problem: 
ERROR finding paper-drawer-panel.css paper-item-shared.css paper-menu-shared.css page.js

Solution:
The gulpfile.js -> task copy needs to be corrected. The bower_components  must be copied from the ./app directory.

OLD

```
var bower = gulp.src([
    'bower_components/**/*'
]).pipe(gulp.dest('dist/bower_components'));
```

NEW

```
var bower = gulp.src([
    'app/bower_components/**/*'
]).pipe(gulp.dest('dist/bower_components'));
```